# Memoir Show Trims in TwoSide

Tags: memoir

I have to show trims in twoside document. I need twoside because I need the header.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright,showtrims,titlepage]{memoir}
\setstocksize{297mm}{210mm}    
\settrimmedsize{202mm}{130mm}{1}%
\settypeblocksize{150.1mm}{95mm}{*}%altezza x larghezza
\settrims{2.5cm}{5.5cm}
```

But what I get is [image]

How can I:
1. get the headers (different between even and odd pages)
2. show the trims ?

Comment: Please provide a complete MWE (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`);  you can use `lipsum` for any text. Your code is wrong in that `{memoir}` should come at the end of `\documentclass[...]` not after `\settrims`. You have probably missed `\checkandfixthelayout` but as you show virtually no useful code its hard to tell.

Comment: yes,right, I mis-pasted the code. is it necessarey \checkandfixthelayout?

Comment: `\checkandfixthelayout` is very necessary! I really ought to add some kind of automatic warning if users forget it

Comment: It has been a week since you were asked to provide an MWE. I hope nothing traumatic has happened in your life. If It has please ignore the following. I assume that that (a) you have solved your problem or (b) you are no longer interested in a solution. If (a) then please post an answer. If (b) then is there any reason to keep the question? I spent considerable time trying to come up with an answer for you which I now feel was wasted effort. GUM.

Answer (score 1):

Following the comments from @Peter I solved by reducing the stocksize.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside, showtrims,openright,titlepage]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}% 
\setstocksize{210mm}{140mm}   
\settrimmedsize{210mm}{140mm}{*}%
\settypeblocksize{150.1mm}{95mm}{*}%h x w   
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt}
\setulmargins{2.9cm}{*}{*}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.5}

 \checkandfixthelayout
 \fixpdflayout
```

The important commands are `\checkandfixthelayou`t and `\fixpdflayout`

Comment: `\fixpdflayout` is executed automatically at the beginning of the document.